# app-drawer-layout not repainting

Tags: dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

The default behaviour of the app-drawer-layout is, that the app-drawer is next to the content. Polymer calculates a "margin-left: 256px;" for the "#contentContainer", so that the drawer does not overlap the content. However, because I am loading this view via an "iron-pages" element, Polymer does not calculate the margin. The drawer overlaps the content.

If I resize the window, Polymer adds the margin. How can I force a repaint, so that the containers do not overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the resetLayout() method on the app-drawer-layout element.